# Formatting a problematic USB Drive

Tags: debian, partition, usb-drive, readonly

So, today I partitioned my 8GB USB stick in 2 partitions (5-3 GB). In the 3GB partition I launched the `dd if=/path/to/file of=/dev/sdcX; sync` command (like written in the Debian site) to copy the Debian ISO. For distraction I removed the USB stick. After this the USB was always mounted in read-only and I can't formatting, I tried with gparted, `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdcX` and other ways found after googling, but the USB stick doesn't work. Can you help me?

This is the output of `ls -l /dev/sdc`:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 32 nov 27 13:26 /dev/sdc
```

---

ps: I apologize if I wrote some mistakes. My english isn't yet perfect.

Comment: What do you mean by "*For distraction I removed the USB stick.*"? Did you wait until `dd` and `sync` exited? Have you tried re-partitioning the drive (using `gdisk`/`gparted` etc.)? Are all the other partitions also read-only? Is there anything **relevant** in `dmesg`?

Comment: It means that I removed the USB drive before the dd command ended. And yes I tried to re-partitioning with gparted but it failed. All partitions in the USB drive are read-only

Comment: Have you rebooted then tried to re connect the flash drive to use gparted?

Comment: I tried from another PC with LINUX and the problem is the same

Comment: What does `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdX` where X is the usb drive. Confirm your usb drive with `lsblk`. You will need to run the mount command with sudo or root permissions.

Comment: @kemotep I tried your command but it returned with this error: `mount: /dev/sdc: mount point not mounted or bad option`

Comment: Please [follow the advice here](https://askubuntu.com/a/175742) and report back if it works. The key take away is that you should make sure the device is "unmounted" and then try mounting the specific partitions to a specific directory such as `/mnt/flashdrive`. E.G. `sudo mount -o rw,remount -force /dev/sdc1 /media/flashdrive`

Comment: So, I putted the key into usb port, the OS mounted automatically a partition and I proceeded in this way: I unmounted the partition and I checked the block devices with `lsblk`, all partitions of the USB key were unmounted. I used your last command to mount but it had no effects. I tried for each partition but no effects

Comment: Was there an error message you could then update your post with? Edit your question to include all the steps you took to reach the error message please.

Comment: no error message was given to me

Answer (score 4):

You should write Debian ISO with

`dd if=/path/to/file of=/dev/sdY; sync` (change the `Y` to the correct letter. Read carefully it is very very similar to what you did.).

Not in a partition.

Just do it again (properly), and it should fix it. If you want another partition, then you need to learn more about how it works. Start with the basics. Get that to work. Then progress from there.

## To give yourself permission to do the operation

```
sudo chgrp floppy /dev/sdY
```

Check that you have changed the correct file: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path` etc.

```
sudo --group floppy -s
```

Now do the operation.

Comment: sorry for my delay but i had some problems. I tried your solution many times but for each one the system send me the message `dd: failed to open '/dev/sdY': Read-only file system`. I also used other systems like gparted but nothing works.

Comment: You don't have permission. You need to change the permission, double check that it is the correct device, then do the operation. Show the output of `ls -l /dev/sd*`.

Comment: This is the output about `ls -l`:
`brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 32 nov 27 13:26 /dev/sdc`